# How to remove the halo created in HDR?

Tags: post-processing, hdr

I use Oloneo HDRengine to process bracketed photos into HDR images.

I am often left with a halo around objects against the background of the sky.

If I am happy with the rest of the image, is there a method for removing the halo (from the sky, for example)?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up copying one of the mid-tone bracketed images into the bottom layer, and masked out the sky of the HDR image on the layer above it.  Looks okay.

Answer (score 2):

Cloning the original is certainly one way to do it, but really the best option (IMHO) is to get the look that you're happy with in post.  I don't know about HDREngine, but certainly with Photomatix Pro, that I use, there are lots of sliders and settings for exactly how the image should be processed.  I believe that microcontrast is the main culprit for the halo you describe.  If you can, try reducing that slider to see how it affects your image :)